# Virtual String Tree Drag and Drop

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь реализовать Drag&Drop в VirtualStringTree, но узлы не драгаются. Разрешил, обработчики сделал, не пойму что не так. Заполняется событием OnGetText.

```
procedure TfrFuelKinds.vstFuelKindsDragAllowed(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; var Allowed: Boolean);
begin
 Allowed := True;
end;

procedure TfrFuelKinds.vstFuelKindsDragDrop(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Source: TObject; DataObject: IDataObject; Formats: TFormatArray;
  Shift: TShiftState; Pt: TPoint; var Effect: Integer; Mode: TDropMode);
var
  pSource, pTarget: PVirtualNode;
  attMode: TVTNodeAttachMode;
begin
  pSource := TVirtualStringTree(Source).FocusedNode;
  pTarget := Sender.DropTargetNode;

  case Mode of
    dmNowhere: attMode := amNoWhere;
    dmAbove: attMode := amInsertBefore;
    dmOnNode, dmBelow: attMode := amInsertAfter;
  end;

  Sender.MoveTo(pSource, pTarget, attMode, False);end;

procedure TfrFuelKinds.vstFuelKindsDragOver(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Source: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; State: TDragState; Pt: TPoint;
  Mode: TDropMode; var Effect: Integer; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := (Sender = Source) and (Sender.DropTargetNode  <> Sender.FocusedNode);
end;
```

Comment: Отбой. Разобрался. Просто не поставил toFullRowDrag в TreeOptions --> Misc

Comment: Вопрос теперь в другом. Как мне перетасовать элементы массива. Суть в следующем: в массиве данные разных типов в порядке "число, строка, число". Вот при перемещении нода нужно перетасовывать массив. Если перемещение над, то все до target.index-1 сдвигаются влево, а от target.index-1 заполняются значениями из source.index. В случае перемещения под - все то же самое, только target.index берется. Кажется, пока писал, сообразил. Сделаю - напишу :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так у меня вышло. Может можно как-то по-другому?

```
procedure TfrFuelKinds.vstFuelKindsDragDrop(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Source: TObject; DataObject: IDataObject; Formats: TFormatArray;
  Shift: TShiftState; Pt: TPoint; var Effect: Integer; Mode: TDropMode);
var
  i, startPos, endPos, idxSource, idxTarget: Integer;
  arr: TFuelsInfo;
begin
  idxSource := TVirtualStringTree(Source).FocusedNode.Index;
  if not Assigned(Sender.DropTargetNode) then
    Sender.DropTargetNode := Sender.GetLast;

  idxTarget := Sender.DropTargetNode.Index;

  SetLength(arr, 3);
  startPos := idxSource * 3;
  endPos := (idxTarget) * 3;

  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
    arr[i] := FFuelsInfo[i+startPos];

    for i := 1 to 2 do
    begin
      FFuelsInfo[startPos] := FFuelsInfo[endPos];
      FFuelsInfo[endPos] := arr[startPos mod 3];
      Inc(startPos); Inc(endPos);
    end;
  Sender.InvalidateNode(TVirtualStringTree(Source).FocusedNode);
  Sender.InvalidateNode(Sender.DropTargetNode);
end;
```